# Wake on Lan on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, suspend, wakeonlan

There is a computer in lab I need to turn it on wakeonlan, I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan). I used gWakeOnLan tool to wake up the system. The default `UDP port number is 9` and i checked from the [website](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) that port is blocked in my network. so i thought any other will work which are open in my network but nothing worked for me I tried `80, 443, 22, 23,20, 14000`
Help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to forward the external port to your internal network. You are most likely under a firewall/router that blocks incoming external connections.

Comment: how do I forward the the external port to internal network ?
and yes we have firewall installed and they use [Microsoft Forefront Threat Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront_Threat_Management_Gateway) and like I said few ports are open cant i redirect my connection to those ?